# replace all int's in string with _

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I separate data types in a string or list so they can be set to another character, I assume there is something I have missed but everything i have tried so far has now worked for me. so far have tried so split into list and use a for loop to find every int but I can't find a way to differentiate the data types so it can change every int.

[image: desired output]

Comment: Please provide your code, what isn't working about the code, and what the expected output is. Provide them in the form of an edit to your original question; do not use the comment section for these things.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regex](https://realpython.com/regex-python/) :

```
import re

re.sub("\d", "_", "10 4 2")
```

- \d matches any decimal digit character.

Comment: Good answer but the raw string isn't necessary